# Eclipse Xcore tutorials or documentation

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf, ecore, xcore

I'm in charge of prospecting technologies to create a DSL (Domain Specific Language).  As we are a Java shop, we've met already with the Eclipse Modeling Framework offerings (EMF, Sirius, Acceleo, Xbase, Xtend), and it seems we have their documentation, including published books.

However, there's a newer project, Xcore, that seems quite promising (as other innovative projects derive from it, such as efactory and incquery), but so far we've found only scant documentation on Xcore.

Can anyone refer us to updated documents/forums/blogs regarding Eclipse XCore, or confirm if the project is dormant or defunct?

Comment: do you know https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore ?

Comment: I would join this question. The page mentioned by Christian is the only resource in the web (excluding forums). I also struggle with some more advanced usages of xcore (derivation of variables for example)

Answer (score 1):

The Xcore project is not dormant. However, there is not much documentation on it. The primary source is https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore. Also Lorenzo's book "Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend - Second Edition" has a section on Xcore, which also is not more than the Wiki page.

You should be aware of the fact that Xcore is actually using Xbase, so it is worth to learn about Xbase (but you already know it, since you mention it in your technology stack).

I recently wrote a blog on integrating Xcore with Xtext and Gradle 3: https://blogs.itemis.com/en/using-xtext-with-xcore-and-gradle.

Further, there is Holger Schill's presentation from XtextCON "Using Xcore with Xtext": http://de.slideshare.net/holgerschill/using-xcore-with-xtext.